# Oversensitive touchpad

Tags: touchpad

Following a recent upgrade, I find that my touchpad (Dell Inspiron 5110) is extremely sensitive, and doesn't even need to be touched to activate.  I have tried just disabling it through "prefences" and using a real mouse, but every few power cycles, it re-enables.  If I could just keep it disabled until I have time to fix the problem, I would be content.
Advice please.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could use `synclient TouchpadOff=1` in the terminal and use `synclient TouchpadOff=0` to turn it back on.

Comment: ...provided you use the synaptics driver. However, nowadays, the libinput driver is more common.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 navigate to Settings->Devices->Mouse & Touchpad 
and in Touchpad Block Manage Touchpad Speed to moderate.

[image: Lock for description]